the output of sigmoid 's requires_grad is False, while the input 's requires_grad is True
I have a module defined as follows:
class MoR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, work=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.sparsity = 0
        self.scores = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(-4.0))
        self.f = torch.sigmoid
        self.threshold = self.f(self.scores)

        self.min_loss = float('inf')
        self.sparsity_best = 0  # used for training

        self.sparsity_loss = 0
        self.recon_loss = 0

        self.work = work

        self.num = 0
        self.sparsity_avg = 0

    def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor):
        if self.work:
            # get mask
            mask = self.generate_mask(inputs)
            if torch.sum(torch.isnan(inputs)).bool():
                import pdb
                pdb.set_trace()
            self.get_sparsity(inputs)
            self.update_sparsity_avg()
            print("mask:", mask.requires_grad)
            print("scores:", self.scores.requires_grad)
            print("sparsity:", self.sparsity.requires_grad)
            print("threshold:", self.threshold.requires_grad)
            return inputs * mask
        else:
            return inputs

In this module, scores has requires_grad=True, but after computation, requires_grad for other parameters is False. Even the simplest threshold with requires_grad is also False. I don't understand why this is the case.
The threshold is computed as sigmoid(scores), which should definitely be differentiable.
This situation occurs when I insert this module into an LLM (Large Language Model).
However, when I apply this module to a small model, all training is normal.
Here is the small model:
class LinearModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LinearModel, self).__init__()
        self.mor1 = MoR(work=True)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()  # Add ReLU activation layer
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(1, 1)  # A simple linear layer
        self.mor2 = MoR(work=True)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()  # Add ReLU activation layer
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.mor1(x)
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)  # Apply ReLU activation
        x = self.mor2(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)  # Apply ReLU activation
        return x


It's very strange. I don't understand if there's some underlying mechanism that automatically sets requires_grad to False for its outputs.
Note that I haven't found an answer in GPT or online forums, and possibilities such as whether no_grad() context is used, computation graph breaks, device transfers, or data usage are all non-existent, as shown in the code, it's just a sigmoid operation.
        print("mask:", mask.requires_grad)
        print("scores:", self.scores.requires_grad)
        print("sparsity:", self.sparsity.requires_grad)
        print("threshold:", self.threshold.requires_grad)

the parameter's requires_grad is True

In your post, you mentioned that

In this module, scores has requires_grad=True, but after computation, requires_grad for other parameters is False. Even the simplest threshold with requires_grad is also False. I don't understand why this is the case.

However, according to my test case, self.threshold.requires_grad=True. Please check the following code:
import torch.nn as nn

class MoR(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, work=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.sparsity = 0
        self.scores = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(-4.0))
        self.f = torch.sigmoid
        self.threshold = self.f(self.scores)
        print(self.scores.requires_grad, self.threshold.requires_grad)

MoR()  ## True True

Therefore, your statement is wrong. Maybe you can check this video to know more about computational graph (BP) in PyTorch.
Hope that you find this answer would be helpful.

Thank you very much for your answer, as it has inspired me to debug. Since I am using the trainer from the transformers library for training, I set gradient_checkpointing to True to prevent gradients from becoming NaN, but I did not fully understand what would happen. After debugging line by line, I finally found that this gradient checkpointing might cause some gradients not to update. I will now carefully look for the reason behind this.

because this function:
    def gradient_checkpointing_enable(self, gradient_checkpointing_kwargs=None):
